# Remove element from array by position

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm trying to figure out how to remove an element from an array if its in a certain position. We would also need to resize the array.  To make the example easier, let's try remove whatever color is in position one in the array ("green", "blue", "red").

```
Sub Example()

Dim pos
colors = Array("Green", "Blue", "Red")

pos = 1

colors(pos).Delete 'obviously this doesn't work but what would the correct protocol be?

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the specific element to a single blank and **TRIM()** it out of existence:

```
Sub DropFirstElement()
    Colors = Array("Green", "Blue", "Red")
    Colors(0) = " "
    Mystring = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(Join(Colors, " "))
    Colors = Split(Mystring, " ")
End Sub
```

Note:

We use the worksheet's *Trim()* function rather than VBA's *Trim()* function to remove multiple sequential spaces.

Comment: Good use of the worksheet function's [TRIM function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRIM-function-410388FA-C5DF-49C6-B16C-9E5630B479F9) to reduce internal double spaces to a single space character which VBA's [Trim function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9wz3dez%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) does not perform. I believe that the [Join Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b65z3h4h%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) uses a single space as the delimiter by default (i.e. not provided).

Comment: Well, defaults are for people with are familiar with the various functions. It never hurts to spell things out.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of the difference between the two `Trim` functions.

Answer (score 6):

You could also use `Filter` (if the values were unique as in this example any string matching *Green* is removed).

```
Colors = Array("Green", "Blue", "Red", "Yellow", "Pink")
Colors = Filter(Colors, Colors(0), False)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can shift the values in the array starting at the *pos* then [ReDim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2.aspx) to its new dimensions.

```
Sub Example()

    Dim pos As Long, p As Long, vCOLOURs As Variant

    vCOLOURs = Array("Green", "Blue", "Red", "Purple", "Pink")

    For p = LBound(vCOLOURs) To UBound(vCOLOURs)
        Debug.Print p & ": " & vCOLOURs(p)
    Next p

    'vCOLOURs is an array dimmed 0 to 4
    pos = 3
    'vCOLOURs(pos) is 'Purple'

    For p = pos To UBound(vCOLOURs) - 1
        vCOLOURs(p) = vCOLOURs(p + 1)
    Next p
    ReDim Preserve vCOLOURs(0 To (UBound(vCOLOURs) - 1))

    For p = LBound(vCOLOURs) To UBound(vCOLOURs)
        Debug.Print p & ": " & vCOLOURs(p)
    Next p

End Sub
```

Results from the VBE's Immediate window (Ctrl+G)

```
example
0: Green
1: Blue
2: Red
3: Purple
4: Pink
0: Green
1: Blue
2: Red
3: Pink
```

Remember that the method you are using to put values into your variant array is creating a zero-based array. The first value is at `vCOLOURs(0)`, not `vCOLOURs(1)`.